# Using <select> value as javascript var

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the paragraph to be the selected value.

```js
var char = document.getElementById("character").value;

function build() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = char;
}
```

```html
<select onchange=build() id=character>
                <option value=dog>dog</option>
                <option value=cat>cat</option>
                <option value=moose>moose</option>
            </select>
<p id=output>#</p>
```

Comment: Move `var char = document.getElementById("character").value;` inside the `build()` function

Comment: because you  read the value when the page is rendered.... It does not magically update, value is not live.

Answer (score -1):

I have just modified your code, check out

```js
function build(val) {
  console.log(val);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = val;
}
```

```html
<select onchange=build(value) id=character>
                <option value=dog>dog</option>
                <option value=cat>cat</option>
                <option value=moose>moose</option>
            </select>
<p id=output>#</p>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!